# Database design: Custom data layout and rights management

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm workling on a project for my University and im a little curious about my current database design:

First of all, what is the common naming practice for a database table: singular or plural? I once read something about i but i cannot remember it?! (e.g. table: user or users)

The second question is a little mor specific to the project:

The users can login into the website an have to choose 10 elements out of a list and attach each of the elements a priority from 1 to 4. My first try was to save the choice of the user in a single row as a CSV (e.g. 1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8;9,10 which represents the choice of element 1,2,3 with priority 1 etc.). The second attempt was to save each choice as a single entry like: [user_id]|[choosen_element]|[choosen_priority]. What do you think is the better variant or is there a even better one that i havent thought of?

The third question is more about the login and rights management:

The elements that the users can choose from are in groups. Each element can be in multiple groups. There are moderators who have the same groups that the elements have or a subset of it, and they can edit all elements of the group they are in posession of. Besides the groups there are also the rights for the users e.g. user, moderator, admin etc.

In my last design i defined the rights of the users as part of the groups table so that every user that is in the moderators group can edit items of the groups that he is also in.

In my first attempt i had the groups and the rights in a seperate table with a seperate logic in my application!

Is it better to seperate the aplication rights from the groups?

Here is a plot of my current layout if i missed something, or if somebody just likes to look at pictures ;)

http://screens.rofln.de/2012-06-19-4f3o3A.png

Thanks!

Btw.: Im working with PHP and a MySql if someone whants to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is subjective, but if you go by conventions supplied by popular ORMs, it seems pluralized is pretty common. I don't think which you chose matters, only that you are consistent once you have chosen.
2. A record representing each choice makes most sense. This allows for ordering as well as queries to find highly rated elements, etc. Finally, reading the data in your application, and varying how it is displayed, will be easier since you'll be working with a list of items rather than a packed value.
3. This is hard to answer, since I'm not familiar with your problem domain. I'd recommend developing use cases and then applying them to your proposed model to see where the cracks are.

Answer (score 1):

1. It does not matter whether you use singular or plural, what matters is that you are consistent in your use of the standard.
2. Comma separated values in MySQL are *bad*, mostly because it is not a congruent way of using a relational database. A standard database relationship, or a many-to-many table is a better idea.
3. When you make your rights management system more flexible, it becomes more complex. A good heuristic in this case is to **build the simplest system that satisfies your requirements, but no simpler**.

Speaking of simplicity, why do you have a separate table for userdata? Do you expect some user to have two sets of names and details?